# Is there any directory convention for placing of Swagger definitions and for the generated code?

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm having a Java project built by *Gradle*. I'm wondering if there is some already established convention of "default" directory structure for placing *Swagger* definitions and possibly the location of the generated artifacts?

I was searching Google, but didn't find anything decisive.

For now, I'm working with the following layout:

```
Project
|----src/main/swagger            (YAML, or JSON definitions)
|----src/generated/swagger       (generated artifacts)
```